# Email to groups in the same domain bounce due to spam

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, google-groups, domain

I am a admin of a domain that uses gmail. In the past week gmail started bouncing email sent to a group (user to user emails still work) from a user in the same domain. If the email is sent to the group from someone outside the domain the email goes through with out an issue.

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

    senior_signup_forwarding@halomonitoring.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Message rejected by Google Groups. Please visit http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 to review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines.

----- Original message -----

Received: by 10.216.22.129 with SMTP id t1mr2909819wet.20.1318788916453;
       Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:15:16 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.216.22.129 with SMTP id t1mr2909818wet.20.1318788916431;
       Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:15:16 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <senior_signup+caf_=senior_signup_forwarding=halomonitoring.com@halomonitoring.com>
Received: from mail-ww0-f44.google.com (mail-ww0-f44.google.com [74.125.82.44])
       by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id s49si8111787wec.91.2011.10.16.11.15.16
       (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
       Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:15:16 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 74.125.82.44 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of senior_signup+caf_=senior_signup_forwarding=halomonitoring.com@halomonitoring.com) client-ip=74.125.82.44;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 74.125.82.44 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of senior_signup+caf_=senior_signup_forwarding=halomonitoring.com@halomonitoring.com) smtp.mail=senior_signup+caf_=senior_signup_forwarding=halomonitoring.com@halomonitoring.com
Received: by wwe6 with SMTP id 6so1159934wwe.1
       for <senior_signup_forwarding@halomonitoring.com>; Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:15:16 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.227.19.193 with SMTP id c1mr5581848wbb.24.1318788916158;
       Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:15:16 -0700 (PDT)
X-Forwarded-To: senior_signup_forwarding@halomonitoring.com
X-Forwarded-For: senior_signup@halomonitoring.com senior_signup_forwarding@halomonitoring.com
Delivered-To: senior_signup@halomonitoring.com
Received: by 10.180.102.103 with SMTP id fn7cs81624wib;
       Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:15:14 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.68.42.9 with SMTP id j9mr32444367pbl.6.1318788913272;
       Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:15:13 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <myHalo@halomonitoring.com>
Received: from dfw-web3.halomonitor.com (dfw-web3.myhalomonitor.com. [67.208.39.198])
       by mx.google.com with ESMTP id w9si15916407pbv.245.2011.10.16.11.15.11;
       Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:15:13 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 67.208.39.198 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of myHalo@halomonitoring.com) client-ip=67.208.39.198;
Received: from halomonitor.com (dfw-web3.halomonitor.com [127.0.0.1])
       by dfw-web3.halomonitor.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id A444478096
       for <senior_signup@halomonitoring.com>; Sun, 16 Oct 2011 13:15:11 -0500 (CDT)
Date: Sun, 16 Oct 2011 18:15:11 +0000
From: myHalo@halomonitoring.com
To: senior_signup@halomonitoring.com
Subject: [HALO] Order Summary
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Message-Id: <20111016181511.A444478096@dfw-web3.halomonitor.com>
```

Comment: Do you still face those problems?